# laravel storing images on database with full path and I cant retrieve

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm making a site where you can store files by a form, and after it'll show on a page.

this is my form to insert:,

```
 <form action="{{ route('post.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="bg-grey-lighter pt-15">
                    <label
                        class="w-44 flex flex-col items-center px-2 py-3 bg-white-rounded-lg shadow-lg tracking-wide uppercase border border-blue cursor-pointer">
                        <input type="file" name="thumb" class="hidden">
                    </label>
                </div><br>
```

this is the code I'm using to show the image:

```
            <img src="{{  asset('/images/posts/' . $post->thumb }}" class="img-post" />
            <br>
```

this is my PostController: (thumb is the name of the field on database)

```
    public function update(Request $request, Post $post, $id)
    {


        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
      
        $path = public_path('images/');
        $imageName = time(). '.' . $request->thumb->extension();  
        $post->thumb = $request->thumb->move($path, $imageName); 


            $request->validate([
                'thumb' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif',
            ]);
    

        $post->update();
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'updated');
    }
```

and in the database is storing like this:

```
C:\Users\users name\Documents\laravel\projeto-qbv2\public\images/posts\1700092184.png
```

and in laravel the images are storing in:

```
public\images\posts
```

tried already to change the function, the img src...

Comment: If all your images are always stored/retrieved from the `images\posts` URL I think it would be enough to only store the image name in the database - don't store the folder with it. This way, if you intend to rename that folder you don't have to update all image paths in your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use laravel file storage system.

first of all you need to configure your storage symbolic link.
you can do it by running this commande in artisan CLI:

```
    php artisan storage:link
```

You may configure additional symbolic links in your filesystems configuration file. Each of the configured links will be created when you run the storage:link command:

```
'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    public_path('images') => storage_path('app/images'),
],
```

After that, You can simply use the storage functions:

your PostController.php code would be like this :

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post, $id)
{


    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $request->validate([
            'thumb' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif',
        ]);
    if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {

    $path = $request->logo->store('/images');
    $post->thumb = $path;

    $post->update();
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'updated');
    }
  
    
}
```

this is the code you should be using to show the image:

```
        <img src="{{  asset('/storage/' . $post->thumb }}" class="img-post" />
        <br>
```

For more information about this i recommend Laravel Documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem

Comment: thanks a lot! 
about the img src, I reworked it to work: 
"<img src="{{  asset('storage/') .('/'). $post->thumb }}" />"